# Links don't open in external browser in JQuery Mobile with PhoneGap

Tags: jquery, ios, cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm having a problem in PhoneGap 2.3.0 with JQuery Mobile 1.2.0.

Any external link iniOS opens inside the app instead of opening Safari they open inside the app, making it impossible for user to get back to the app without rebooting it.

I have tried both **rel="external"** and **target="_blank"** to indicate it's an external link, but none with success.

I have seen that the default way that PhoneGap with JQMobile should act is the way I want. I have found lots of requests for this kind of behaviour, but not the way around.

Comment: did u add the desire link to the white list ?

Comment: Yes I did. Actually * is whitelisted during development.

Comment: i assume that u are testing on Android.
anyway u got your answer by @asgeo1 ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I added `rel="external"` to my anchor links.

And then added/overrided the `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` method in the `MainViewController` class:

```
- (BOOL) webView:(UIWebView*)theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSURL *url = [request URL];

    // Intercept the external http requests and forward to Safari.app
    // Otherwise forward to the PhoneGap WebView
    if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"http"] || [[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"https"]){
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
        return NO;
    }
    else {
        return [super webView:theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:request navigationType:navigationType];
    }
}
```

That works for me in jQuery Mobile 1.2 and Phonegap 2.2.0.  It should work the same in Phonegap 2.3.0 - but I haven't tested that.

==================================================================================

**UPDATE**:

There may not be any need to do this in Phonegap 2.7.0 or above. Phonegap can now open links in either of the UIWebView, Safari or the InAppBrowser component. Personally I like the InAppBrowser component, as it seems to be a better user experience for a lot of use cases. If you want to open links in Safari you can now do this now using Javascript:

```
window.open('http://whitelisted-url.com', '_system');
```

or this for the InAppBrowser:

```
window.open('http://whitelisted-url.com', '_blank');
```

Have a look here for more information:

http://wiki.apache.org/cordova/InAppBrowser
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser

Comment: That did not do the trick. The same behaviour keeps happening. The link open in the same page blocking the user from getting back in the app.

Comment: @gusfune - I've updated my answer. Sorry, I got confused and pasted in the wrong code snippet. The correct method to override is `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` in `MainViewController`

Comment: Works fine with Phonegap 2.4.

Comment: The code has been moved in phonegap 2.5.0. Ive put your `if` on line 557 of CDVViewController.m and .. it works. This will override all the target, rel, config, javascript stuff that didnt work. Its definitely a hack.

Comment: It's worth noting that the window.open() approach also works in 2.5, which is supported by PhoneGap Build, if you're using that service.

Comment: I`m using window.open but that doesnt seem to work. I`m using PhoneGap Build with v3.5.x Any suggestion what i can do?

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want to override the classes or dig too deep in code as suggested, try this.  It worked like a charm for me.  I'm using Phonegap Build and jQuery Mobile.

*Note - I tried several other ways of adding attributes directly to the anchor tags e.g. `<a href="http://externalsite.com target="_blank" data-rel="external" data-ajax="false">` also tried `target="_system` - but none worked, so I had to use javascript (only 5 lines though).

It's not too complicated but I'll walk you through it...

1. You need to prevent the default behavior of the anchor tag. So somehow grab onto the a tags you care about.  I added a class called "external" to all the anchor tags I wanted to open externally.  Pretty standard stuff:

   ```
   $(document).on('click', ".external", function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
   };
   ```
2. Then grab the `href` value from the anchor you're trying to load in safari. Again, nothing too fancy added here:

   ```
   $(document).on('click', ".external", function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();

       var targetURL = $(this).attr("href");
   };
   ```
3. This was the bit that took some digging - I guess Phonegap changed their method on this with 2.3? Anyway, open the grabbed `href` in a new window (here is where `"_system"` comes in):

   ```
   $(document).on('click', ".external", function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       var targetURL = $(this).attr("href");

       window.open(targetURL, "_system");
   });
   ```

That's it.  That last bit of code is everything.  At least that's what worked for me.

Good luck!

(To give credit where credit is due, here is what helped me most: http://www.midnightryder.com/launching-external-urls-in-phonegap-again-phonegap-2-4-x/)

Comment: `$(this).attr("href")` is the same as `this.href` for a link. well almost.

Comment: .. but it didnt work either (in phonegap 2.5.0, without jquery mobile, and not using phonegap build) :~/

Comment: This didn't work for me on Android and Phonegap 2.7.0. Like @pike, I'm not using Phonegap Build. Still upvoted it because the solution is clever, follows documentation exactly, and SHOULD work. Very frustrating.

Answer (score 7):

The same solution as @KyleSimmons, but just inline, and shorter. but a simple fix. And works great for me.

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/" onclick="window.open(this.href,'_system'); return false;">Google</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

To open an external link in jQuery Mobile:

```
<a href="http://moorberry.net" data-rel="external">Like this</a>
```

Comment: The key to the question is that he is using Phonegap. So I don't think Phonegap is going to obey any data attributes that jQuery Mobile creates.

Comment: I have tried this one, it gives me the same behavior that I'm trying to fix :/